# undefined URL in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a simple extension that gets URL of the current tab and saves it to the storage when I click a 'create' button and retrieve URL when 'goto' button clicked.

I got undefined tab and url debugging this code. I'm new to chrome extension and javascript and would appreciate your help! :)))

this is my popup.js

```js
$(function() {
    $('#create').click(function() {
        var tab;
        var myUrl;
        chrome.tabs.query({active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true}, function(tabs){
            tab = tabs[0];
            myUrl = tab.url;
        });

        chrome.storage.sync.set({'newUrl': myUrl});

    });
});
```

popup.html

```
 <script src= "jquery-3.4.1.min"></script>
    <script src = "popup.js"></script>;


</head>
<body>
    <input type = "button" id = "create" value = "create">
    <input type = "button" id = "go" value = "go to">
 </body>
```

manifest.json

```
"permissions": [
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "bookmarks",
    "contextMenus",
    "storage",
    "*://*/*"
],
```

Comment: I don't know the API but I'd say there's a very high possibility that `chrome.tabs.query()` is asynchronous. You should call `chrome.storage.sync.set()` in the callback function provided to `query()`

Comment: It would be better if you can provide more code...with the proper file names so that can check and can try to provide the exact solution.  chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true, active: true }, function (tabs) {
  console.log(tabs[0]);
});

Comment: @Vishal I added more code

Comment: @Xxx, Thanks....let me check and will get back to you very soon. If possible, then try to add the code of creating tab from.background.js...you can use message passing action to call the function in background.js from popup.js

Answer (score 0):

`chrome.*` apis can be accessed from background and popup scripts only.
You have written those `chrome.*` api in injectedScript or content script.